# Can you run a whole service using Redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

So I'm currently developing a messaging application to learn the process and I'm actually using Redis as a cache and use it with websockets to push real-time messages.

And then, this question popped in my mind:

**Is it possible, to use Redis only to run a whole service (like a messaging application for example) ?**

**NOTE :** This imply removing any form of database (we're only keeping strings)

I know you can set-up Redis to be persistent, but is it enough ? Is it robust enough ? Would it be a safe enough move ? Or totally insane ?

What are you thoughts ? I'd really like to know, and if you think it is possible, I'll give it a shot.

Thanks !

Comment: My vote - give it a shot, see where it falls short. Nothing wrong with experimenting

Comment: Should be fine, especially if you run a master/slave setup with sentinel in front.

Comment: That would mean setting up Redis on a EC2, and not using ElastiCache right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few companies use Redis as their unique or primary database, so it is definitely not insane.

You can develop and run a full service using Redis as a backend, as long as you understand and accept the tradeoffs it implies.

By this I mean:

- that you can use a Redis server as a high performance database as long as your whole data can reside in memory. It may imply that you reduce the size of your data, or choose not to store some of them which may be computed by your app on read access or imported from another source;
- that if you can't store all of your data in the memory of a single server, you can use a [Redis cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), but it will limit the available Redis features (see [implemented subset](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec)
- that you have to think about the potential data losses when a server crashes, and determine if they are acceptable or not. It may be OK to lose some data if the process which produced them is robust and will create them again when the database restart (by example when the data stored in Redis come from an import process, which will start again from the last imported item). You can also use several Redis instances, with different persistency configuration: one which writes on disk each time a key is modified, avoiding potential data loss, but with much lower performances; and another one to store non critical data, which are written on disk every couple of seconds.

Redis may be used to store structured data, not only strings, using hashes. Each time you would create an index in a relational model, you have to create a data structure in Redis. By example if you want to store Person objects, you create a HASH for each of them, to store their properties, including a unique ID. If you want to be able to get people by city, you create a SET for each city, and you insert the ID of each newly created Person in the corresponding SET. So you will be able to get the list of persons in a given city. It's just an example, you have to define the model and data structures to be used according to your application.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer ! (I'll wait a few more days before validating it, to see if there could be more opinions). Now, you said `It may be OK to lose some data if the process which produced them is robust and will create them again`, in my case of a messaging app, where I need the messages to be persistent, Redis is probably a wrong choice of unique database right ?

Comment: My answer was rather general indeed; your app obviously does not fall into this case. It's not easy to give you a definitive answer. It would heavily depend on the requirements of the application, so it's a bit out of the scope of stack overflow. If you want to minimize potential losses, you may imagine different options: use another database in addition to Redis and use Redis only for its pub/sub features, use multiple Redis instances with different configurations, etc...